# Problem with Microsoft Clipchamp video editor leaving files stored on hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, video

I use Microsoft's clipchamp video editor to produce multiple videos and shorts for You Tube  on my Linux Mint computer. Clipchamp stores data on your hard drive gthat needs to be manually deleted. The stored files can run up to tens or hundreds of gigabytes of data and at that point clipchamp seizes up.

Can anybody tell me where the files from apps are stored on Ubuntu as they are likely to be in there. Clipchamp works in the chromium browser rather than being on the machine itself. I have looked through videos on how to remove the stored data on a Microsoft computer but I haven't found one about how to remove it on a Linux computer.once I knw where the files are stored it should be easy to remove them.

Deleting the data files from the browser partof clipchamp does not remove the stored data from your hard drive which is an issue with clipchamp.

Also can anyone recommend a good video editor made for ubuntu that I can use instead.

Thanks for your help

Mike Ward

Comment: Mint is off topic here.